# Separable field extensions and base change

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields

Suppose that there are field extensions
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \longrightarrow & K \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
L & \longrightarrow & M
\end{array}
where $M$ is generated by $L$ and $K$ (in other words there is a sujection $K \otimes_k L \twoheadrightarrow M$).

Suppose that $k \subseteq K$ is a separable field extension (or geometrically reduced). This means that every finitely generated subextension $k \subseteq K^{\prime} \subseteq K$ is separably generated ([Tag030O](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030O)). I would like to show that $L \rightarrow M$ is also separable (or geometrically reduced). I have seen this result when all extensions are algebraic and I am wondering if it admits such generalisation.

Comment: No: for $p=\mathrm{char}(k)>0$, take $K=M=k(x)$ (pure transcendental),  $L=k(x^p)\subset M$.

Comment: Great. Thank you!